# Inverse $z$ transform - contour integration

Tags: inverse, contour-integration, residue-calculus, complex-integration, z-transform

Here is my task:

Find inverse $z$ transform of $$X(z)=\frac{1}{2-3z}$$if $$|z|>\frac{2}{3}$$ using definition formula.

I found that $$x(n)=\dfrac{1}{3}\left (\dfrac{2}{3}\right )^{n-1}*u(n-1)=\dfrac{1}{3}\left (\dfrac{2}{3}\right )^{n-1}, n=1,2,3,...$$ (using other method). But how can I find it using definition formula, $$x(n)=\frac{1}{2\pi j}\oint_{C} X(z)z^{n-1}dz?$$

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
X(z)=\frac{1}{2 - 3z}
\end{equation}

The result could be found by using

(i)  Geometrical Series:
       (a) Left Series, 
    \begin{equation}
      X(z) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{ 1}{1 - 3 z/2} 
      =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^n (z^{-1})^{-n}
      =\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{-\infty} \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^n (z^{-1})^{n},
    \end{equation}

```
from which the coefficients are
```

\begin{equation}
      x[n] = \frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^n
     \quad n < 1
    \end{equation}

This infinite series converges for $|z|<2/3 \, , \, |1/z| > 2/3$.

```
  (b) Right Series
```

\begin{eqnarray}
  X(z) &=& \frac{1}{z(2 \, z^{-1} - 3)} \\
  &=&
  \frac{z^{-1}}{(2 z^{-1} -3)} \\
  &=& -\frac{1}{3} \frac{z^{-1}}{( 1 - (2/3) z^{-1})} \\
  &=& - \left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )
  z^{-1} \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{2}{3} \right )^i z^{-i}
\end{eqnarray}
from which
\begin{eqnarray}
  X(z) = 
  - \left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left (\frac{2}{3} \right )^n z^{-n-1}
  =
  - \left ( \frac{1}{3} \right )
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left (\frac{2}{3} \right )^{n-1} z^{-n}
\end{eqnarray}
and then

\begin{eqnarray}
x[n] = -\frac{1}{3} \left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{n-1}
= -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^n
\end{eqnarray}
with $n \ge 1$, and converges for $|z^{-1}| < \frac{3}{2}$ or
$|z| > \frac{3}{2}$.

(ii) Contour Integration: 
We know that
\begin{equation}
x[n] = \frac{1}{2 \pi \mathrm{i}} \oint_C X(z) z^{n-1} dz.
\end{equation}
We can use the Cauchy residue theorem. That is,
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{2 \pi \mathrm{i}} \oint_C X(z) z^{n-1} dz = \sum_{k=1}^n R_k,
\end{equation}

where $R_k$ is a residue.

We further consider several cases:

(a)  $n \ge 1$

For a simple pole (and this is the case here)
\begin{equation}
R_k = \lim_{z \to p_k} (z - p_k) X(z) z^{n-1}.
\end{equation}
since $X(z)=-1/3(z - 2/3)$, then for $p_0=2/3$, we consider the contour as the
unit circle, for which the only pole $p_0=2/3$ is inside.
\begin{eqnarray*}
R_0[2/3,n] &=&
\lim_{z \to 2/3} (z - 2/3) X(z) z^{n-1}  \\
&=&
\lim_{z \to 2/3} \left [ (z - 2/3) \frac{-1}{3 
(z - 2/3)} z^{n-1} \right ] \\
&=&
-\frac{1}{3} \left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^{n-1} \\
&=&  -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{2}{3} \right )^n
\end{eqnarray*}
    from which the coefficients are
    \begin{equation}
      R_0[2/3,n] = -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^n
    \end{equation}

(b) $n < 1$ Since $n$ is integer we are talking about poles at 0 of
multiplicity. If n=0, we get

\begin{equation}
  R_0[0] = \lim_{z \to 0}  z \frac{1}{(2 - 3 z)
    z}
= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{2 - 3 z} = \frac{1}{2}. 
\end{equation}

If $n=-1$ we have a pole of multiplicity 2, from which we apply the formula:
\begin{equation}
R_1[0] = \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d}{dz} \left ( \frac{z^2 X(z)}{z^2} \right )
= \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{d}{d z} X(z) = \frac{3}{4}.
\end{equation}

In general:

\begin{equation}
R_n[0] = \left . \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}} X(z)
\right |_{z=0}
\end{equation}

That is, $R_n[0]$ is the $(n-1)^{th}$ coefficient of the Taylor series
expansion of $f(z)=1/(2 - 3 z)$.

This is:

\begin{equation}
R_n[0] = \left ( \frac{1}{2} \right ) \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^{-n}
\end{equation}

Now we apply the residue equation, and get
\begin{eqnarray*}
x[n]=
\left \{
 \begin{array}{lll}
   -\frac{1}{2} \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^n & n \ge 1  & |z^{-1}| < 3/2 \\
 \\
 \quad \frac{1}{2}  \left ( \frac{3}{2} \right )^{-n} & n > 1 & |z^{-1}| > 2/3
\end{array}
\right .
\end{eqnarray*}

The bilateral Z transform converges in the annulus $2/3 < |z| < 3/2 $
Unilateral Z transforms converge for |z|<3/2  and |z|>2/3

Comment: For "inverse z transform" he wants a series in $z^{-1}$.  Convergence near $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks GEdgar. I thought so. I am geophysicist and we use a different convention......I underestimated the size of the problem.....will try harder. An y ideas?